# Can I write an Android app on NON-Android TV OS to show antenna TV shows?

Tags: android, android-tv, television

We are developing an Android app for Android TV, its OS is not Android TV and it has standard Android. Our device has a hardware antenna port to show TV shows, now my question is... is there any solution to show TV channels in our Android app via antenna or you should go to the TV input source to watch the TV channels? Is NON-Android TV OS supporting antenna TV shows at all without going to TV input source? Is there any solution or document?
thanks

Comment: You would need to ask the manufacturer how to access signals off of what you describe as the "antenna port".

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, I'll check it with the manufacturer.